# AS3 / AIR: Maximize desktop application window on start up (?)

Tags: windows, actionscript-3, air, maximize

It's possible to maximize the AIR generated application window when starting up it in Win OS?

I mean, not full, but maximized. I did search other questions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use [NativeWindow.maximize](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/NativeWindow.html#maximize%28%29) when you initialize the program.